# Send coordinates to server ever 10 seconds

Tags: android, gps

I' creating an app that sending my gps coordinates to server every 10 seconds.
What i have: 
Activity, that starts my service. In service onStart i create location manager:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) this
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(GpsReceiver.GPS_ACTION);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, 0);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, criteria, pIntent);
```

My broadcast register in activity.

```
public class GpsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String GPS_ACTION = "gps.ACTION";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent != null) {
            String key = LocationManager.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED;
            try {
                Location location = (Location) intent.getExtras().get(key);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now i need to send my coordinates to server every 10 seconds.

How i can do this?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`scheduleTaskExecutor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

```
public static ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecutor;

scheduleTaskExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);

private void startThreadOnce() {

    scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(
            new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Send data here.
                }
            }, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // 0 >> initial delay, 10 >> every x., TimeUnit.SECONDS >> in seconds

}
```

call `startThreadOnce()` only once. `run()` method will be executed every 10 seconds.

Kill it onDestroy.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    scheduleTaskExecutor.shutdown();
    scheduleTaskExecutor.shutdownNow();
    scheduleTaskExecutor = null;
}
```

Comment: Can u help me with struct of my program? Where is it good to place this executor. I create one more service(IntentService that send post request) and start it from broadcast when coordinates gets.

Comment: call `startThreadOnce()` at the starting of your service `onStart` with initial delay of 10secs.